# How to programmatically get Integer value of TextView leadingAnchor?

Tags: swift3, autolayout, constraints

I have difficulties around changing TextView Constraints. I don't find any example how to get Integer values of Constraints. I need them for initial values before code execution.

Initial constraints are created in IB, but I need to get value for variable in code to change them with multitouch gestures. I have TextView filled with text for reading. I already arranged that with pinch I can change Font size of text with min and max values. Now I want to change TextView width with rotate gesture.

Here is part of code for pinch gesture to change font size.

```
//Change font size
func pinchRecognized(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    //get pinch value (less than 1) fingers towards each other, (more than 1) fingers apart
    let pScale = pinch.scale
    //get current font size
    let pFont = Int((ReadTextView.font?.pointSize)!)

    if pScale > 1 {
        if pFont <= maxFontSize {
            ReadTextView.increaseFontSize()
        }
    }
    else if pScale < 1 {
        if pFont >= minFontSize {
            ReadTextView.decreaseFontSize()
        }
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }
    defaults.set(pFont, forKey: "FontSize")
}
```

I like now to change width of TextView with rotate gesture. To start shrink I need initial values of left (leading) and right (trailing) margins.

Comment: Are the constraints being created in code or Interface Builder? What difficulty are you having exactly?

Comment: Initial constraints are created in IB. After changing they will be stored for next time initialisation.

Comment: Is there nobody to have any solution?